# Drawing a rectangle in a canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am trying to make a game. I have a `mainActivity` which is called `BridgeScene`, and a class for the enemy. In the `mainActivity` I have two `ImageView`s and some buttons.

In my class, I have an enemy (represented by a rectangle) and I use a `Canvas` to draw a rectangle. What I need is to draw this rectangle on my `BridgeScene` Activity. How can I do that?

I cannot set the `contentview` twice because it is already set in the activity as

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_bridge_scene);
```

So how can I draw my rectangle from my enemy class in my `BridgeScene` activity?

My activity:

```
public class BridgeScene extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final  int[] ALL_DRAWABLE_RES_EAGLE = new int[]{
            R.drawable.stickmanreturnkick0,
            R.drawable.stickmanreturnkick1,
    };

    private Ennemy1 ennemy1;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final static long Interval = 30;

    private Runnable updateImageTask;
    private int currentDrawableResIndex;

    private static long IMAGE_UPDATE_DELAY_MILLIS = 30;

    private ImageView imvStickman;
    private ImageView imvJump;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bridge_scene);

        ennemy1 = new Ennemy1(this);
        setContentView(ennemy1);

        updateImageTask = new UpdateImageTask();

        imvJump = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imvJump);

        imvStickman = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imvStickman);
        imvEnnemi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imvEnnemi);

        imvJump.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //code//
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My class:

```
public class Ennemy1 extends View{
    public  Bitmap rec;
    public  int recX;
    public  int recY;

    public int canvasWidth;
    public int canvasHeight;

    public Ennemy1(Context context){
        super(context);
        rec = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.enem1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(rec, 100, 100, null);
        canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Comment: If your Enemy1 is inside the contentView the draw method will be called on rendering the scene

Comment: but if the enemy1 is inside the contentview, it will clear up my activity where i put all my images

Comment: As @David says you should add your image to the layout with the proper class

Answer (score 0):

You should add something similar to your activity_bridge_scene.xml file

```
<com.your.package.Ennemy1 
    android:id="@+id/enemyId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: it is not the response i am looking, i need to draw the image from my ennemy class into my activity, not to draw it using an imageview